# python encoding mysql :(

Tags: python, mysql, encoding

I have the follow python script (tes.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb

query = "INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES ('ñ')"
print query + "\n"

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "ibrick", passwd = "x", db = "ibrick", charset="utf8")
conn.names="utf8"
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute (query);
cursor.close ()
conn.commit ()
```

file encoding utf-8:

```
 $ file -i tes.py 
tes.py: text/x-java charset=utf-8
```

system encoding UTF:

```
#locale
LANG=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
echo "ñññ" > /tmp/test.txt

file /tmp/test.txt 
/tmp/test.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

MYsql table encoding UTF8:

```
mysql> show create table test;
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                 |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test  | CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `test` varchar(10) default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 | 
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Console outupt is OK:

```
#./tes.py 
INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES ('ñ')
```

problem:

The script doesn't insert ñ in the table.. it inserts a bad character:

```
select * from test;
+------+
| test |
+------+
| �    | 
| �    | 
| �    | 
| �    | 
| �    | 
| �    | 
| �    | 
+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Anybody help me??

Thank in advance!

Comment: Have you tried SELECT with python? It might be stored correctly but get messed up in console output of MySQL.

Comment: The smily and the footer don't help you get answers, I would leave them out in future.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding 'use_unicode'.

> The secret ingredient is to add a charset=”utf8″ to your connection
>   parameters, and use_unicode=True. [Source](http://www.harelmalka.com/?p=81)

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PASS, db=DB_NAME, charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
```

Comment: thank Latty! but, by adding "use_unicode=True" continue the same problem :(

Comment: @HalNuevemil Hrm, I'm afraid I don't know then. I would check your console supports unicode, just in case it's in the DB fine but doesn't display correctly.

Comment: exctly Latty, I checked the table out by PhpMyAdmin Tool and the data is correct.. it maybe a visualization problem in mysql console. it's crazy because my locale is UTF-8 in my system..

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me so I have a hunch you'll need to do this _and_ alter your database's collation, for example with; ALTER DATABASE database CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: This answer was correct then? Should have accepted it

Answer (score 3):

```
import MySQLdb

# connect to the database
db = MySQLdb.connect("****","****","****","****") #don't use charset here

# setup a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8mb4;") #or utf8 or any other charset you want to handle

cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;") #same as above

cursor.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;") #same as above

# run a sql question
cursor.execute("****")

...

#and make sure the mysql settings are correct, data too
```

Comment: +1 Not clear why this was down-voted earlier. Useful information.

Comment: The only thing working for me

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL client uses latin1 as its default character encoding.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set

Use `--default-character-set=utf8` when starting the mysql client.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
query = u"INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES ('ñ')"
```

along with `use_unicode = True`.

Comment: I tried but continue the same problem, I think the data is enserted as ISO charset because when y get the data by php I get it in ISO and not in UTF.

Comment: more data:

if I try this:

mysql  -u ibrick -pxx -h localhost ibrick -N -B -e "INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES ('ñ')"

is OK, y see

: | ñ   | 
+------

but if I try with:

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb

query = u"INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES ('ñ')"
print query + "\n"

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "ibrick", passwd = "ibrick", db = "ibrick", charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
conn.names="utf8"
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute (query);
cursor.close ()
conn.commit ()

I see | �    |

Comment: Well, if you're saving the file in ISO-8859, don't tell Python it's UTF-8; set the `# -- coding:` to the actual file encoding you saved with.

Comment: I want to save the data in UTF-8.. my system is UTF-8, mysql table is utf-8, the file script is utf-8, everything is UTF-8,,  I don't know why the data is saved in ISO.. I'm really confused ..