# Python encoding when retrieving from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, encoding

In MySQL I have a field with the value: `"Rœschwoog"`

The charset of the MySQL table is UTF-8.
When I retrieve that value from Python 3.4, I save it into a dict. When I print that dict, I realize that the value is not `"Rœschwoog"` but `"R\x9cschwoog"` instead. Why is this happening? How can I get the real value?

I create the MySQL connection with:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='xxx', passwd="yyy", db='mydb')
```

Comment: `"R\x9cschwoog"` is Python's *representation* of the string `Rœschwoog` encoded in the `windows-1252` encoding. Can you please add the relevant parts of your code (a simplified testcase) to your question? Particularly, what connection parameters do you use when creating your MySQL connection?

Comment: Thx for your answer. I edited my previous question with the mysql connection info.

Comment: Try adding `charset="utf8"` to your connection parameters. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8365782/1599111), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9155014/1599111) and the [pymsql docs](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) for some more details.

Comment: Gread, glad I could help. I'll therefore flag your question with the appropriate duplicate, if I think that's correct you should be able to confirm that and immediately mark it as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Not `charset=utf8`, you need to specify that your bytes are encoded `cp1252`, or perhaps `latin1`  (They are similar.)